# Fire validation rule while opportunity stage change

Tags: apex, validation

I want to fire validation rule when opportunity stage is moving from Customer Intake to Opps Planning.

When opportunity stage change it should check that Account.Mask_Manufacturer_Model__c is not null when Respiratory__c =true.

What i have done so far is as below any idea how can i achieve that?

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName ,'Opps Planning' ), 
ISBLANK( Account.Mask_Manufacturer_Model__c ), Respiratory__c =true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Add OR condition. If your stage is `Opps Planning` and any one `Mask_Manufacturer_Model__c` null or `Respiratory__c` false then fire validation rule..

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName ,'Opps Planning') , 
 OR(ISBLANK( Account.Mask_Manufacturer_Model__c ), Respiratory__c =false))
```

---

### Updates

Use `PRIORVALUE`fuction to check old value

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName ,'Opps Planning') ,
     ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName ),"Customer Intake"),
 OR(ISBLANK( Account.Mask_Manufacturer_Model__c ), Respiratory__c =false))
```

,

Comment: In this where it check that it will fire only when opp stage change Customer Intake to Opps Planning.

Comment: ALso tried what you told but getting and error like Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'. If i add missing syntax then i am getting another error like Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 3

Comment: All right, This is working fine, but what i am saying is there are multiple stage,  this will fire when any stage change to opps planning, i want to fire this only when  Customer Intake stage change to Opps Planning.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate that. Thats working like charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey there is one problem, this rule is always fire, it not validate on base of Respiratory__c(checkbox) value.  Do you know what we are doing wrong here?

Comment: @puravthakkar What I understood..  Your `Respiratory__c` will be false or `Account.Mask_Manufacturer_Model__c ` any one of is null or false then validation rule should fire ?

Comment: No No, If Respiratory__c = True then Account.Mask_Manufacturer_Model__c cannot be null, or Respiratory__c = False then Account.Mask_Manufacturer_Model__c can be null or value.

Comment: I got this, changed OR to AND, works fine now. Thanks